# SSDT Installed on VS2013 But Can't Find SSIS Project template

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have SSDT 2010 projects that I would like to checkin in a TFS 2015. In order to do that I have to upgrade the current SSDT projects to VS2013. Now, I have installed VS 2013 but I can't find the SSIS template.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you install SSDT for VS 2013? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313

Comment: When I go to the "About VS 2013" I can see that SSDT is already installed..

Comment: Did you install the SSIS bits and/or the SSDT-BI bits?  It's been a while since I used VS2013 for the IDE so I don't remember if they had an integrated SSIS and SSDT package for VS2013.  However, if you don't have the SSIS/BI bits installed, you'll need to do that.  (Brief history - MS messed up when they did the initial naming. SSDT == the DB Projects, then "SSDT-BI" was everything else. Led to much confusion. Now the SSDT installer for VS2015 can handle all of the components.)